# Passing different names of a data.frame to function

Tags: r, function, reshape2

I'm missing very basic here. I looked many examples but could not figure out the following problem.

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Rep = factor(rep(1:3, each = 4, times = 2)),
  Gen = rep(paste0("T", 1:4), times = 6),
  Env = rep(paste0("Loc", 1:2), each = 12), 
  Y   = rnorm(24)
)

GEMeans <- 
  function(data, G, E, Y){
    G   <- deparse(substitute(G))
    E   <- deparse(substitute(E))
    Y <- deparse(substitute(Y))

    Means <- 
    reshape2::acast(
        data          = data
      , formula       = data[[G]] ~  data[[E]]
      , fun.aggregate = mean
      , margins       = TRUE
      , value.var     = data[[Y]]
    )
    return(Means)
  }


GEMeans(df1, Gen, Env, Y)

Error in `[.data.frame`(df, vars) : undefined columns selected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slight modifications to your call to `acast` solve the problem.

```
GEMeans <- 
  function(data, G, E, Y){
    G   <- deparse(substitute(G))
    E   <- deparse(substitute(E))
    Y <- deparse(substitute(Y))
    Means <- 
    reshape2::acast(
        data          = data
      , formula       = as.formula(paste(G, E, sep = "~"))  # here
      , fun.aggregate = mean
      , margins       = TRUE
      , value.var     = Y    # and here
    )
    return(Means)
  }
```

Try it, it works.